# Parsing values from string into dictionary

Tags: python, json, string

Let's say I have string y, I am trying to extract substrings to convert into Dictionary separated by =.

```
y = '''

Cat ID=456789       Cat Name=Cosmo           Home=Tree\n

Cat ID=567890       Cat Name=Winksie           Role=Cute\n

'''

[
    {
        "Cat ID": "456789",
        "Cat Name": "Cosmo"
        "Home": "Tree"
    },
    {
        "Cat ID": "567890",
        "Cat Name": "Winksie"
        "Role": "Cute"
    }
]
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: His question is more about regex than dictionaries.

Comment: teshtalks, I think you may want to temporarily close the question to look into regex oriented questions/answers. What I think you need is to understand how to extract pieces of text with the "re" module.

Comment: I'm sorry, *what does this question have to do with JSON*? You seem to want to create a `dict`...

Answer (score 0):

This regex should select the key=value pairs.

```
[ ]?.*?=.*?[ \n]
```

[ ]? 0 or 1 space

.*?=  any number of any character until first encounter of =

.*?[ \n] any number of any character until first encounter of either space or \n

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do it without regex:

```
lst = []
for line in [line for line in y.split('\n') if line]:
    record = dict(it.split("=") for item in line.split("  ") if (it := item.strip()))
    lst.append(record)
print(lst)
```

It gives:

```
[{'Cat ID': '456789', 'Cat Name': 'Cosmo', 'Home': 'Tree'}, 
 {'Cat ID': '567890', 'Cat Name': 'Winksie', 'Role': 'Cute'}]
```

Alternatively, with regex:

```
lst = [dict(re.findall(r"(\w[\w ]+)=(\w+)", line)) for line in y.split("\n") if line]
```